# CSS file not found error 404 when I try to run flask code

Tags: python, css, http-status-code-404

I am fairly new at programming practising web development. I have a problem with my css file in that when I link it to my html and run the python code it produces an error that the css file is not found. Here is the link to the git repository. Thanks in advance.
https://github.com/NelsonNNN/SecondApp.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the root directory, create a folder called `static`.
2. Move `css` folder to `static`.
3. In `layout.html`:

replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}">
```

Comment: thanks a lot man this worked. but i am curious as to why it would not just pick up on the css file directly...or is this the new format to be used?